# htaccess rewrite on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with my .htaccess file, my problem is I have site on localhost and path to it is: 
`localhost/site/sitename/html/login.php?ref=company`
and after uploading to server would be:

```
www.site-name.com/login.php?ref=asdas
```

What I needd to do is rewrite ref to looks like this (in both cases):
path_to_site/company/login.php
where company is 
`$_GET['ref']`
For ex. I have this url:

`localhost/site/sitename/html/login.php?ref=cola`

And I want have this:

`localhost/site/sitename/html/cola/login.php`
How to do it?

Comment: please read this article and you will understand how to do it. http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ . Also just for testing and understanding, also check this  http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php

Comment: make a subdomain on your localhost so you have a real root path. Your local url should look like this: `http://sitename.localhost/login.php?ref=company`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)/$login.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site-name.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

I hope I understood what you want correctly. Also check if you have everything enabled and configured on your server correctly.
Look @ http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for more information if youre using Apache.